# Debian stuck in Endless DHCPNAK/OFFER loop unless I ask DHCP server to clear expired leases

Tags: debian, networking, dhcp, hostname

have a Marvel Kirkwood device running Debian with 3.16 Kernel.  On boot, the DHCPClient gets stuck in a loop and never picks up an ip unless I log onto the dhcp server and ask it to dump the expired leases.  The dhcp server has no issue with any of the other 25 devices in the place.

I feel this has something to do with the device rejecting the hostname that the dhcp server is trying to push on the device.  Not sure how and if the device can announce it's hostname to dhcp server.

**Edit:** When it does finally pick up an ip, the DHCP clients list shows its name as new-host and not the actual device name.

```
 [   34.300664] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
 DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 
 DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1 
 DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 
 DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 
 DHCPOFFER from 192.168.2.1 
 DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1 
 DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 
 DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1 
 DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 
 DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 
 DHCPOFFER from 192.168.2.1 
 DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1 
 DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 
 DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1 
 DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 
 DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 
 DHCPOFFER from 192.168.2.1 
 // CLEARED the 'expired DHCP leases'  
 DHCPACK from 192.168.2.1 bound to 192.168.2.24 --renewal in 100664 seconds.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with Debian on Cubox.

Looking at the log file on the DHCP server (running dhcpd OpenBSD) however revealed what the problem was in my case:

```
Oct  4 08:45:04 gateway dhcpd[22743]: Both dynamic and static leases present for 192.168.1.2.
Oct  4 08:45:04 gateway dhcpd[22743]: Either remove host declaration 192.168.1.2 or remove 192.168.1.2
Oct  4 08:45:04 gateway dhcpd[22743]: from the dynamic address pool for 192.168.1.0
```

The mistake I had made was to both assign static IP addresses to some hosts based upon their MAC addresses and then have the same IP addresses available in the dynamic pool (the range part on the DHCP server).

Answer (score 0):

the dhcp client at /etc/dhcp/dhcp/dhclient.conf was sending gethostname(); as the hostname to the dhcp server.

Replaced gethostname() with the hardcoded name of the device and it has fixed the issue.

Comment: How do I know the device name?

Comment: @GuySoft `cat /etc/hostname`

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud Thats the host name, not the device name. But I don't really remember what i did here anymore.

Comment: maybe could be more specific about "device"

Answer (score 0):

I got problems with my **DHCP Server** (Router) with reserved addresses

Remove them and reallocate them solved my problem